При парсинге сайта TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable. Как вытащить ссылку?
Хочу спарсить сайт с фильмами, но не понимаю, как вытащить нужную ссылку. В devTools это выглядит так:
<div class="th-item">
<a class="th-in with-mask full-link" href="https://sub1.lordfilm-man.net/fantastika/986-megan-k-vashim-uslugam-2024.html"> 

Вот мой код:
url = 'https://sub1.lordfilm-man.net/'
response = requests.get(url)

data = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
film_data = data.find('div', class_="th-item")

link = film_data.div.a['href']
print(link)

Объясните, как вытащить ссылку? Сейчас получаю ошибку:

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable


link = film_data.a['href']
